# Verilog code: initializing an 2D array using nested for loop

Tags: for-loop, multidimensional-array, verilog

I'm recently trying to store a 2D array whose elements are consisted of 8-bit integers(0~4) by first input its elements row by row (treating it as an 1D array) and then access the values in the 1D array.
my procedure is as follow:

1.initialize an 2048-bits-1D (8*16*16) array (Row1 in the code) in test bench as input

2.cut the 1D array every 8 bits and assign the 8-bit number to the elements in the 2D array

3.use another 1D array (Row2 in the code) to observe the final result, because an array cannot be used as an instance output
So actually i'm turning an 1D array with 256 8-bit elements into a 2D array with 16*16 8-bit elements.

the problem is that after running the simulation,
it seems that most of the elements in the 2D array is in a high z state,
while the last of them have been assigned new value correctly.
Can anyone explain what's going on and how can i fix it?

To be clear, i put my verilog code below:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module convPE(
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input [2048:1] Row1,
    output [2048:1] Row2
    );
    wire [7:0] arr[17:0][17:0];

    generate
    genvar i,j;
    for(i=16;i>=1;i=i-1)
    begin:gen1
        for(j=16;j>=1;j=j-1)
        begin:gen2
            assign arr[i][j]=Row1[(8*i*j) -: 8];
            assign Row2[(8*i*j) -: 8]=arr[i][j];

        end
    end
    end generate
endmodule
```

And here is the test bench :

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module testbench;

    // Inputs
    reg [2048:1] Row1;
    reg Clk;
    reg Reset;

    wire [2048:1] Row2;
    convPE uut (
        .clk(Clk),
        .reset(Reset),
        .Row1(Row1),
        .Row2(Row2)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        Row1=2048'd0;

        Row1[1784:1777]=8'd1;//1
        Row1[1584:1577]=8'd1;
        Row1[944:937]=8'd1;
        Row1[376:369]=8'd1;
        //2
        Row1[1720:1713]=8'd2;
        Row1[1600:1593]=8'd2;
        Row1[1488:1481]=8'd2;
        Row1[1480:1473]=8'd2;
        Row1[1368:1361]=8'd2;
        Row1[1344:1337]=8'd2;
        Row1[1336:1329]=8'd2;
        Row1[1120:1113]=8'd2;
        Row1[1112:1105]=8'd2;
        Row1[1080:1073]=8'd2;
        Row1[1072:1065]=8'd2;
        Row1[1056:1049]=8'd2;
        Row1[984:977]=8'd2;
        Row1[936:929]=8'd2;
        Row1[856:849]=8'd2;
        Row1[808:801]=8'd2;
        Row1[728:721]=8'd2;
        Row1[680:673]=8'd2;
        Row1[608:601]=8'd2;
        Row1[592:585]=8'd2;
        Row1[584:577]=8'd2;
        Row1[576:569]=8'd2;
        Row1[568:561]=8'd2;
        Row1[560:553]=8'd2;
        Row1[544:537]=8'd2;
        Row1[472:465]=8'd2;
        Row1[424:417]=8'd2;
        Row1[416:409]=8'd2;
        //3
        Row1[1712:1705]=8'd3;
        Row1[1592:1585]=8'd3;
        Row1[1472:1465]=8'd3;
        Row1[1360:1353]=8'd3;
        Row1[1352:1345]=8'd3;
        Row1[1240:1233]=8'd3;
        Row1[1208:1201]=8'd3;
        Row1[1200:1193]=8'd3;
        Row1[1064:1057]=8'd3;
        Row1[992:985]=8'd3;
        Row1[928:921]=8'd3;
        Row1[864:857]=8'd3;
        Row1[736:729]=8'd3;
        Row1[600:593]=8'd3;
        Row1[464:457]=8'd3;
        Row1[456:449]=8'd3;
        Row1[448:441]=8'd3;
        Row1[440:433]=8'd3;
        Row1[432:425]=8'd3;

    //4
        Row1[800:793]=8'd4;
        Row1[672:665]=8'd4;
        Row1[552:545]=8'd4;


        #100
        Reset=1'b1;
        #100
        Reset=1'b0;
        Clk=1'b1;

        // Add stimulus here

    end
   always
    #50 Clk=~Clk;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

This `(8*i*j)` does not work. You have two nested loops so i in the second loop must increment in steps of 16. (The size of the inner loop) Try 8*(i*16+j)-1

Your code is somewhat inconsistent in that you sometimes use 0 and sometimes 1 as lowest index. I suggest you make all your arrays and vectors start from 0. [2047:0] It is the Verilog convention.

---

I have converted your code using the Verilog conventions I use. I also removed all superfluous signals like clock and reset. With the following code there are no X-es or Z-es in either `Row2` or in `arr`.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module convPE(
    input [2047:0] Row1,
    output [2047:0] Row2
    );
    wire [7:0] arr[15:0][15:0];

    generate
    genvar i,j;
    for(i=0; i<16; i=i+1)
    begin:gen1
        for(j=0; j<16; j=j+1)
        begin:gen2
            assign arr[i][j]=Row1[(8*(i*16+j)) +: 8];
            assign Row2[(8*(i*16+j)) +: 8] =arr[i][j];
        end
    end
    endgenerate
endmodule

`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module testbench;
    // Inputs
    reg [2047:0] Row1;
    wire [2047:0] Row2;

    convPE uut (
        .Row1(Row1),
        .Row2(Row2)
    );

    initial begin
        #100; // I want to see X-es first
        // Initialize Inputs
        Row1=2048'd0;
        #100;
        $stop;        
    end
endmodule
```

The reason I use my method is because it is the standard way of mapping N-dimensional arrays of a certain type onto memory (which is linear) like e.g. C compilers do.

You can use 2048:1 but then you have to think much harder how to convert the indexes to a one-dimensional array. Probably replace the i and j in my formula with something like i-1,j-1.

Comment: well, using 8*(i*16+j)-1 may cause the array index out of range.
And the reason for using [2048:1] as the index is for the convenience of the following computation. The 0 and 17 index are for zero padding, since they doesn't cause a fetal error i think i'll keep this expression. btw still thanks for your advice:)